# How to sum column values based on selected column ID in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a python beginner and using pandas and numpy for my data analysis projects. I have encounter a problem as details below:-
I am trying to sum the column 'Votes for ALL Candidate' and 'Total Registered Votes' based on the column 'Type' groupby 'DUN' and 'PARLIMEN'. i have used the following codes but failed. Seek your advised on this. TQ

```
df4 = pd.read_csv('Election-Results-2018 - Total_Votes_by_Seat.csv').drop(['State','Seat','Seat ID','Turn Out','Spoilt Votes'],1)

df4['Votes for ALL Candidate'] = df4['Votes for ALL Candidate'].str.replace(',','')

df4['Total Registered Votes'] = df4['Total Registered Votes'].str.replace(',','')

indexNames = df4[(df4['Type'] == 'PARLIMEN')].index

df4.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)

df4.groupby(by=['Type']).sum().sort_values(by='Type', ascending=False)
```

df4

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have string values for 'Votes for ALL Candidate' and 'Total Registered Votes'. Try to convert those columns to floats with `df['Votes for ALL Candidate'] = df['Votes for ALL Candidate'].astype(float)` and `df['Total Registered Votes'] = df['Total Registered Votes'].astype(float)`

Comment: Thank you, sir. I have done accordingly and have managed to get what I want. You can refer to my report at https://zzahir1978.github.io/projects/GE14.html. This report still in progress and not concluded. Thank you again and really appreciate your assistance.